# Custom Application class: Constructor vs. onCreate()

Tags: java, android, constructor, oncreate

One of my Android apps uses a custom Application class to perform some global initialization. This done in the `onCreate()` method:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        someCustomInit();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but now I have discovers a crash log in the Developer Console which indicated that `MyApplication.onCreate()` did not run / has not completed at the time the crash happened: The code crashed because some initialization that is performed `MyApplication.onCreate()` was not complete.

**How is this possible?** I assumed that  `MyApplication.onCreate()` would run before all other code? Isn't that correct?

**Is it save to move `someCustomInit();` to the constructor of `MyApplication` instead?** No other code should run before the application object has been created, correct?

Or are there any side effects from using the constructor instead of `onCreate()`?

Comment: show crash log here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that MyApplication.onCreate() would run before all other code? Isn't that correct?

`ContentProvider` instances are created before `onCreate()` is called on the `Application`. In theory, your stack trace should show you what code of yours is being invoked prior to your initialization.

> Is it save to move someCustomInit(); to the constructor of MyApplication instead?

That would depend on what is happening in `someCustomInit()`. Your `Application` is not initialized yet.

Another possibility is to override `attachBaseContext()`, such as how [ACRA is hooked in](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup#configuring-acra---compile-time). There, you are passed a `Context` object that you can use, if your initialization requires a `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Application` class is a singleton for your app process, but its `onCreate()` is not the first possible code to execute. Class field initializers, the constructor as well as any `static` code blocks (often used for loading native libs) will execute first. The `static` code blocks, in particular, will run when the class is loaded by the runtime.

Normally, this is not a problem and your safest route is to put your specific code in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 2):

> How is this possible?

It is possible since `Application` class `onCreate` is called for **every process** of your app.

For example `Service` can be started in separate process so your Application can be started twice. I have met this behaviour when used `Yandex.Appmetrica` library. It is not bad actually, because crashes in library will not affect other parts of application.

> Or are there any side effects from using the constructor instead of
>   onCreate()?

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application):

> The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is
>   instantiated before any other class when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

So constructor will be called twice. Any difference?

You should move your code that supposed to run only once to somewhere else, outside `Application` class. Probably in some `Singleton` which will be called from `Launcher Activity` or smth. Actually if you see [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java) of `Application` class you will see that comment:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way.